# how to merge two databases with same schema, using the entry with latest timestamp

Tags: sqlite

I want to merge two SQLite3 databases with same schema with unique keyword. But while merging if two entries from two databases are found to be same, then I want to merge the entry which has the latest time stamp.

For example I have two databases:
1. student_old.db
2. student_new.db

Schema for both DB is:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
 'idx' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
 'name' CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
 'age' INTEGER NOT NULL default 0,
'lastUpdateDate' timestamp DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')),
  UNIQUE (name)
  );
```

Entries for two dbs are:

```
student_old.db 
---------------
sqlite3 student_old.db
SQLite version 3.6.20
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from student;
1|abcd|20|2015-03-01 00:32:29
2|efgh|22|2015-03-01 00:32:29
3|ijkl|24|2015-03-01 00:32:29
sqlite>

student_new.db 
---------------
sqlite3 student_new.db
sqlite> select * from student;
SQLite version 3.6.20
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
1|abcd|28|2015-03-01 00:32:34
2|mnop|26|2015-03-01 00:32:34
3|qrst|27|2015-03-01 00:32:34
sqlite>
```

I am merging the student_new.db to student_old.db with the below query

```
sqlite3 student_old.db <<"EOF"
attach './student_new.db' as toMerge;
BEGIN;
insert or ignore into student (name, age,lastUpdateDate)
select name, age, lastUpdateDate from toMerge.student;
COMMIT;
.q
```

So after the merging I will get

```
sqlite3 student_old.db
SQLite version 3.6.20
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select * from student;
1|abcd|20|2015-03-01 00:32:29 ------>>>> I got the time stamp of student_old.db
2|efgh|22|2015-03-01 00:32:29
3|ijkl|24|2015-03-01 00:32:29
5|mnop|26|2015-03-01 00:32:34
6|qrst|27|2015-03-01 00:32:34
sqlite>
```

But I want to merge the entries of same record but with the latest time stamp.
Something like this:

```
sqlite> select * from student;
1|abcd|20|2015-03-01 00:32:34 ------>>>> I want entry of latest time stamp for 
same record.
2|efgh|22|2015-03-01 00:32:29
3|ijkl|24|2015-03-01 00:32:29
5|mnop|26|2015-03-01 00:32:34
6|qrst|27|2015-03-01 00:32:34
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that `student_old` rows with an older timestamp get replaced, you have to explicitly delete them:

```
ATTACH 'student_new.db' as toMerge;

BEGIN;

DELETE FROM student
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM toMerge.student
              WHERE name           = main.student.name
                AND lastUpdateDate > main.student.lastUpdateDate);

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO main.student(name, age, lastUpdateDate)
SELECT name, age, lastUpdateDate
FROM toMerge.student;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Yes the query you have mentioned worked well for my requirements.
Thanks :-)